# Azure EventGrid event-subscription: error 400: XML specified is not syntactically valid

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I need to listen to events from Azure Blob storage.
I am following the steps in this tutorial [Quickstart: Route storage events to web endpoint with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart).
I have created the message endpoint from the pre-built web app that is provided by Microsoft. 
Now I try to create the event with the following commands (copied from the tutorial)

```
storageid=$(az storage account show --name dealhubsftpintegrations --resource-group Dealhub --query id --output tsv)
endpoint=https://dealhubsharon.azurewebsites.net/api/updates
az eventgrid event-subscription create \
  --source-resource-id $storageid \
  --name dealhubsftpintegrations \
  --endpoint $endpoint
```

I get the following response

```
Argument 'resource_id' has been deprecated and will be removed in version '2.1.0'. Use '--source-resource-id' instead.
If the provided endpoint does not support subscription validation handshake, navigate to the validation URL that you receive in the subscriptionvalidation event, in order to complete the event subscription creation or update. For more details, please visit http://aka.ms/esvalidation
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 8bbe1a84-fe87-460b-b7fb-24fb8a78f952. The attempt to configure storage notifications for the provided storageaccount dealhubsftpintegrations failed. Please ensure that your storage account meets the requirements described at https://aka.ms/storageevents. 
The error is 400: XML specified is not syntactically valid.
```

I have no idea what needs to be fixed. searching the web with the error message gives unrelated results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found out that this (rather cryptic) message means that the storage account is of kind "general purpose v1" and needs to be upgraded to "general purpose v2"